# Solving cycle of beans three datasources

Tags: java, spring, datasource

Look at this code:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "first.datasource")
@Bean
public DataSource dataSourceFIRST() {
    return DataSourceBuilder
            .create()
            .build();
}
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "second.datasource")
@Bean
public DataSource dataSourceSECOND {
    return DataSourceBuilder
            .create()
            .build();
}
@Primary
@Bean
public MyRoutingDataSource routingDataSource(){
    MyRoutingDataSource rDS= new MyRoutingDataSource ();
    rDS.setDefaultTargetDataSource(dataSourceFIRST);
    // some logic for config routing datasource (setting datasources)
    // and creating targed data source tDS
    //rDS.afterPropertiesSet(); (***)

    rDS.setTargetDataSources(tDS);
    return rDS;
}
```

It is getting with error:

```
┌─────┐
|  routingDataSource defined in App
↑     ↓
|  dataSourceFIRST defined in App
↑     ↓
|  dataSourceInitializer
└─────┘
```

Uncomment `(***)` makes this code fine.  However, I can't uncomment `(***)` because it overwrite neccessary config in application.properties.

However, by accident I found solution (it seems to me).
I annotated first and second datasource as `@PostConstruct` (next to `@Bean` annotation - I didnt remove this annotaion).

Can you explain me why it helps ? And if is it ok solution ? Maybe there is someting wrong in this approach.

Comment: You are not supposed to call methods such as `afterPropertiesSet` yourself. The Spring framework will call that method on a bean at the appropriate moment in the initialization process.

Comment: In the `(***)` commented out line, you are calling `afterPropertiesSet`. You're not supposed to do this. This is not a method that you should call yourself, in your own code. The Spring framework will call it at the appropriate time.

Comment: Structure your classes in a different way to get rid of the circular dependency. Circular dependencies are almost never a good idea. Hacks such as manually calling `afterPropertiesSet` or adding `@PostConstruct`, which work by accident (or make it appear as if they solve the problem), are not a good way to make it work.

Comment: So, how do it better? I ask here, because I have a problem.

Comment: As I said, get rid of the circular dependency. You now have a circle: `routingDataSource` depends on `dataSourceFIRST` depends on `dataSourceInitializer` which depends again on `routingDataSource`. Make sure you don't have a cycle like that. You didn't show how `dataSourceInitializer` is configured.

Comment: The problem is that I don;t confiugre dataSourceInitializer  - I am using Spring Boot

Answer (score 3):

In case you would like to try something different.

From my side, I fought for a long time, and still discovered at the end that excluding the class DataSourceAutoConfiguration

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
```

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem.After lot of time I find solution
in this issue:
[Circular dependencies error on Spring Boot's DataSourceInitializer](https://github.com/mybatis/spring/issues/186)

set spring.datasource.initialize = false. hope this can help you.

Comment: `spring.datasource.initialize` is deprecated, you can use `spring.autoconfigure.exclude = org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration` instead.